# Android - how to add two text fields to dialog

Tags: android

I am trying to add to text fields to dialog, but it doesn't seem to be working...  Here is my code.  Can anybody fix my code or give me some guidance ao the about how to add two text fields to the dialog?

Thanks.

```
            final EditText input1 = new EditText(this);
        input1.setText("note");
        input1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                input1.setText("");
            }
        });
        final EditText input2 = new EditText(this);
        input2.setMinLines(1);
        input2.setText("0.0");
        input2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                input2.setText("");
            }
        });
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(1);
        layout.addView(input1);
        layout.addView(input2);


        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
        // code for showing Ok and Cancel button
        .setView(layout).create();
```

Answer (score 5):

create the xml layout file

dialog_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="10dp">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/text1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/text2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

your dialog code

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
View dialog_layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
 // Create the text field in the alert dialog...
EditText text1 = (EditText) dialog_layout.findViewById(R.id.text1);
EditText text2 = (EditText) dialog_layout.findViewById(R.id.text2);        

alertDialog.setView(dialog_layout);
alertDialog.show();
```

you can add more control in layout as per your requirement

Answer (score 3):

I personally use a new activity when i need more than just a few words of dialog. if you add

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</activity>
```

it'll show up as a dialog, allowing you to use multiple TextViews, Buttons, ImageViews, Spinners, etc.

EDIT

Add it to your androidmanifest file for the ativity you want to be a dialog, like this

```
    <activity android:name=".About" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.ABOUT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: +1 i think this is also a best way other than customizing alert dialog.

Comment: I am sorry that I am a beginner to android programming. Where should I create that xml? Under res/layout?

Comment: I was also used to creating an activity. However, I did not like the time it would take the activity to start. So I have switched to using a customized dialog instead. If we create the dialog in `Activity::onCreateDialog()` android manages the life time of the dialog, meaning that subsequent calls to show the dialog may just bring the cached copy back. This dramatically improves the performance. Besides, if you have a lot of data exchange to do between the invoking activity and the dialog, it's much simpler to use dialogs.

Comment: add that code to the androidmanifest file for the intent you want to be a dialog -- added code above

Answer (score 0):

try to add like this

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
     Context c = getBaseContext();
     // Create the text field in the alert dialog...
     text = new EditText(this);
     text.setSingleLine();       

     // Add text to dialog
     alertDialog.setView(text); 
     alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");  
         alertDialog.setMessage("error");  
         alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                       

             }  
         });         
         alertDialog.show();         
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, but only one text field shows up. I need to display two text fields.